# Como bloquear acesso a determinado arquivo no servidor?

Tags: php, apache

Basicamente, possuo um arquivo `JSON` no meu projeto que contém informações que desejo não serem acessadas ao digitar na barra de endereços algo do tipo: www.meusite.com/arquivo.json

E isso vale para outros arquivos. Como posso redirecionar o usuário para a página inicial caso ele digite algo assim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Através do arquivo `.htaccess`...

Se você quer redirecionar pode adiconar essa linha:

```
Redirect /caminho/para/arquivo.json http://dominio.com/arquivo/para/redirecionar.html
```

Se você quer bloquear (código 403 Forbidden), enntão adicione essa:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/caminho/para/arquivo.json$ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

Comment: O redirect realmente funciona. O problema é que preciso ler este arquivo em outras páginas e isto se tornou indisponível...

Comment: O arquivo fica indisponível se tentar acessa-lo diretamente pelo browser, mas você ainda consegue acessar ele normalmente com PHP. Então você pode fazer algo do tipo: `echo file_get_contents("arquivo.php");` e antes definir quem tem acesso

Comment: Humm... isso é bacana. Desculpe minha inexperiência kkkk mas como defino quem tem o acesso?

Comment: Geralmente através de autenticação